# How to restore faded furniture color and sheen

Tags: repair, wood, paint, wooden-furniture

I have a cabinet which is white in color however the white area looks a bit creamy and in some places dirty white. How do I restore the color to what it was when new? Is it possible without necessarily re-finishing it?

Comment: Is the surface melamine (plastic), paint, or something else? It _sounds_ like you may just need to clean it.

Comment: I already tried cleaning it with bleach but that did not work. It is not plastic and it isn't melamine either

Comment: Need to determine what it is before we can tell you what, if anything, can be done with it. "White cabinet, not melamine" sounds likely to be paint, probably a high-gloss enamel... but that's guessing based on what I've seen elsewhere.

Comment: My mistake. It is in fact melamine.

Comment: Anyone in the household smoke?

Comment: No one smokes in this household. Why do you ask please?

Comment: Tobacco smoke can discolor white surfaces gradually over the years;  not as common now as in the past...Not your problem here...